# Image default 400px height, enlarge on click and reduce after second click again

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, toggle

How is it possible to set a image by default to a height of 400px (original more than 600px), enlarge it on click and reduce the size after second click again.

Something like toggling the picture.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example like this:

```
$('.image').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('enlarged');
});
```

CSS:

```
.image {
    max-height: 400px;
}
.enlarged {
    max-height: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<img class="image" src="image.jpg">
```

Comment: Thank you :) Is that also possible with an animation?